How to define, save, and retrieve named filters in Autodesk Tandem?
Is it possible to define multiple filters for a project in Autodesk Tandem and save them with specific names? Additionally, is there an API function to retrieve these saved filters programmatically? If possible, please provide relevant documentation or code examples.

When working with Tandem viewer then probably easiest approach would be to use views - views in Tandem can be saved and restored and include current state of filters etc. To get list of saved views use DtApp.views.fetchFacilityViews. To restore saved view use DtApp.views.setCurrentView - you can find example here.
The view creation is more complicated - there is DtApp.views.createView but view payload isn't publicly documented. If you can provide more details I can look for some examples.

Ok, using sample tutorial-rest-main/views/list-views.js I will be able to iterate over the views of my Tandem-facility.
As user I can open the Inventory to see the filtered elements in a table at bottem.
Is there anoter API function to retrieve that data?

Or in other words: Is there a way to first query the filter criteria via API and then select the data via API?

The sample you mentioned refers to REST API. It can be used but in the context of embedded viewer it's better to use functions I listed above.
Unfortunately when using Tandem Viewer embedded it doesn't provide additional UI elements (filters, inventory etc.) so you don't have access to the filter via its API.
So only option right now is to use Tandem application to create saved view and access filters from there.

To get filters from view use facets.filters - but it may be bit cryptic in some cases.
